# Login Error : there is an error in logging you into this application. please try again later in flutter for android module

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, release, signing

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login for Facebook sign in my app. In debug mode its works fine but after release apk it's showing this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably release keystore file is missing, check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#release-key-hash) and add release keystore file in [facebook developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).